# In Android, can apply different themes in a single XML layout's TextView at runtime without creating a custom widget?

Tags: android, textview, themes

I've seen similar questions here before, but none of them had a satisfactory answer. Basically, I want to have one layout instead of multiple ones and be able to apply themes at runtime. For example, let's take this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SAMPLE HEADING" 
        style="@style/Heading" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And the themes and styles are set up as follows:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:radioButtonStyle">@style/radioButton.Dark</item>
    <item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/checkbox.Dark</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Light" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:radioButtonStyle">@style/radioButton.Ios</item>
    <item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/checkbox.Ios</item>
</style>

<style name="Heading">
    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<style name="Heading.Dark" parent="Heading">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/dark_bg</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16dip</item>
</style>

<style name="Heading.Light" parent="Heading">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/light_bg</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">17dip</item>
</style>
```

So, I want to be able to apply the dark and light `Heading` styles to that TextView by simply applying the dark or light `AppTheme`. And I don't want to apply those styles to all TextViews, but only specific ones. I also don't want to do this programmatically because there are way too many TextViews that would need this done.

Is there a way to do that, or do i have to create two identical XML layouts, where one uses the `Heading.Light` style and the other uses `Heading.Dark`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your use of `parent="..."` property is incorrect.

As [official docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) state:

*"If you want to inherit from styles that you've defined yourself, you do not have to use the parent attribute. Instead, **just prefix the name of the style you want** to inherit to the name of your new style, **separated by a period**."*

So, declaring your style name as `Heading.Light` is enough to specify that it's parent style is `Heading`.

Now to your question. Create a `res/values/attrs.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>  
    <attr name="myTextViewColor" format="reference|color" />
</resources>
```

Then in your `styles.xml` you would declare your theme as follows:

```
<style name="AppTheme">
    <!--parent style. could be overriden by Dark and Light theme -->
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Dark">
    ...
    <item name="myTextViewColor">@color/red</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Light">
    ...
    <item name="myTextViewColor">@color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="Heading">
    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16dip</item>
</style>
```

Now when you apply

```
<TextView ... style="@style/Heading" android:textColor="?myTextViewColor />
```

everything should work just fine. Just **make sure** you apply `AppTheme.Light` or `AppTheme.Dark` theme in your app (as `AppTheme` parent theme would not know the value of your custom attribute).

**Edit:** Also, as  [user496854](https://stackoverflow.com/users/496854/user496854) suggested, there's another simple workaround.

Declare `headingStyle` attr as a reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>  
    <attr name="headingStyle" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

Then in our `AppTheme.Dark` and `AppTheme.Light` styles we would point to a corresponding heading style:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Dark">
    ...
    <item name="headingStyle">@style/Heading.Dark</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Light">
    ...
    <item name="headingStyle">@style/Heading.Light</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear -- the dark and light headings have more items than just the color. I updated the OP to reflect that. So, would I need to create a new ATTR for every item, or is there a way to make the Heading.Dark and Heading.Light styles work?

Comment: I guess there are other ways, but not so efficient. For example, declaring your own class that extends TextView just for that. And after all, why not create attr items? It seems like this is pretty much elegant solution.

Comment: It would have just been much sunnier to create a style for all those attributes, but I'd that's the only way to do it, then it'll definitely do what I need

Comment: Actually, there is a very easy fix, and if you edit you answer, I can mark it as correct. Basically, using your suggestion, I created an ATTR 'headingStyle' as a reference. And then in each theme, I created a 'headingStyle' item that points to the proper light or dark style.

Comment: @user496854, yeah, that's elegant fix. I edited my answer, although did not have time to test it. Feel free to correct me if I am wrong

Comment: I tested it before I posted the last comment. Thanks for your help

Comment: How are the AppTheme.Dark/AppTheme.Light themes applied to the TextView that you wish to theme with the headerStyle attribute? <TextView style="@style/AppTheme.Dark" android:textColor="?headingStyle"/> does not seem to do the job (the value is just ignored).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to crate a class that extends `TextView` and apply your style in it. Use this textView where you want textview with this them and simple TextView where you don't need.